# ReferenceError: BigInt is not defined Asar Electron Nodejs

Tags: node.js, electron, asar

Hello have been trying to extract and repack an app.asar to update files inside the package :

`await asar.extractAll(path.join(__dirname, './app.asar'),path.join(__dirname, './destfolder'));`

Then changing some files in destfolder then

`await asar.createPackage(path.join(__dirname, './destfolder'),path.join(__dirname, './app.asar'));`

But i have been getting this error :

```
ReferenceError: BigInt is not defined
    at new Filesystem (C:\Users\Path\to\project\node_modules\asar\lib\filesystem.js:17:5)
    at Object.module.exports.readFilesystemSync (C:\Users\Path\to\project\node_modules\asar\lib\disk.js:85:24)
    at Object.module.exports.extractAll (C:\Users\Path\to\project\node_modules\asar\lib\asar.js:170:27)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Path\to\project\server.js:221:26)
    at Request.init.self.callback (C:\Users\Path\to\project\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Path\to\project\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Path\to\project\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1090:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Platform : Windows x64
Node version : v14.15.1

I don't know if this is a bug, but i have been stuck on this for about 2 days now and didn't find a solution
I created an issue here : https://github.com/electron/asar/issues/217
Thank you for your efforts, dont hestitate to ask for any information

**UPDATE**

In the node module asar folder package.json :

```
"standard": {
"env": {
  "mocha": true
},
"globals": [
  "BigInt"
]},
```

I tried changing it to :

```
"standard": {
"env": {
  "es2020": true,
"browser": true,
"node": true,
  "mocha": true
},
"globals": {
  "BigInt":true
}},
```

Still i didn't work

**LAST UPDATE RESOLVED**

Electron runs it's own version of nodejs and i hadn't the last package version. Once i updated my electron package, everything worked ! Hope that this will help someone

Comment: This error sounds like you don't have a new enough nodejs version as `BigInt` was added in v10.4 and the error is coming from this line of code in the asar package's `lib/filesystem.js`: `this.offset = BigInt(0)`.  So, I'd suggest you recheck what version of nodejs your builds of electron are actually using.

Comment: Exactly, the thing about it, is that Electron runs a different nodejs version, so i had to update my electron package to get the newest nodejs version and it worked !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is apparently coming from this line of code in the asar package's lib/filesystem.js:

```
this.offset = BigInt(0)
```

And, the error apparently means that you have a version of nodejs that electron is using when it builds your app that does not support `BigInt` which was added in v10.4.

So, though you think you are using v14.15.1, that is apparently not what electron is building your app with.  You need to upgrade the version of nodejs you're using in this electron project.

You can confirm what version of nodejs is being used by adding this to some of your own code in the project:

```
console.log(process.version);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you manage your node version using nvm, please check if `node -v` and `nvm alias default` returns the same node version.

Tools like jenkins, forever... which start nodejs application, will use the default version of node, which could be different than the version used by terminal console.

Do the check: `nvm list`

Fix the difference: `nvm alias default "node -v"`